# Class not registered error after migration

Tags: vb.net

Issue with custom VB.net solution after moving user to new Windows 10.

Removing, re-adding various references.  Cleaning and Rebuilding.

```
Public Class mainForm
    Dim exc As Excel.Application
    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Private wsClient As New WebClient()
    Dim customAccForm As New customAccessories
    Dim custNumArray(4200) As String
    Dim preload As Boolean = False
    Public custName As String = ""
    Public custPhone As String = ""
    Public custAddy, custSuite, custCity As String
    Dim accessoriesprice, accessoriesWeight As Double
    Dim chkQty(20), chkPrc(20), chkWt(20) As Double
    Dim chkCtr As Integer = 0
    Dim chkDsc(20) As String
    Dim currName As String
    Dim updateQuotes As Boolean
    Dim thr, thr2 As Threading.Thread
    Dim bodyTxt, quotedFreight As String
    Public USPS_UserID As String = "USERNAME"
```

I've moved a user from an older Windows 7 machine to a new windows 10 machine.  I have a custom built VB.net application that will not compile on the new machine.  I get a "class not registered" message and the debugger highlights a variable declaration at the top of Forms class.  What's weird is it is on a declaration for a String, the USPS_UserID declaration in the code above.  Even weirder is that I can reorder my declarations and it will show the registration error for another class (String, Integer, Double).  It varies.

Comment: Do you have Excel installed? Is it the same version that was installed on the old W7 machine?

Comment: Are you sure this is VB.NET? I'm asking, because you say it won't **compile** on a user's new PC, you didn't say **run**, and it's throwing an error in code. In this case, either Visual Studio is installed on the user's PC (the user is a developer) - or - this is a VBA Excel/Word macro.

Comment: @HardCode, the syntax is VB.Net. VBA code would not have `Public Class mainForm` nor variable initialization inline with its declaration.

Comment: You should include the actual error message in your question.  Most likely the issue is the Excel references, but we should not have to make educated guesses.  Also tellus what version of the Excel Interop libraries you are compiling against and what version of Excel is installed on the user machine.

Comment: Excel version is Office365, same as before the upgraded machine.  The exact error message is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))'".  When the user experienced the error I immediately tried running it on my computer (Win10/Office365) and got the same error so I'm debugging in VS2015 on my machine.  In testing some more it seems to be an issue with an activeX component from the older Office web components (AXInterop.OWC11 or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Owc11).

Comment: The OWC11 class was used to embed an Excel spreadsheet on my form.  If I try to go to the form designer I see the following...https://imgur.com/a/BxGmXZV